# Ruby OPENSSL AES128 CBC decrypting with random iv not working

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, aes, cbc-mode

I'm using a fairly simple encryption/decryption Ruby script, and it seems to work - BUT the decryption bit corrupts the first few bytes of the message. What am I missing?

Here's the code:

```
key = OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(16)
plain_text = "Some important txt we want to encrypt"
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128.new(:CBC)
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = key
cipher.random_iv
cipher_text = cipher.update(plain_text) + cipher.final

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128.new(:CBC)
cipher.decrypt
cipher.key = key
cipher.random_iv
decrypted_plain_text = cipher.update(cipher_text) + cipher.final

puts "AES128 in CBC mode"
puts "Plain text: " + plain_text
puts "Cipher text: " + urlsafe_encode64(cipher_text)
puts "Decrypted plain text: " + decrypted_plain_text
```

And the outcome:

```
AES128 in CBC mode Plain text: Some important txt we want to encrypt
Cipher text:
P2fdC7cApQvxHnfxSEfB2iJaueK3xRoj-NN3bDR8JheL_VPFYTDF_RxpLfBwoRfp
Decrypted plain text: �܇�Σ }w�D�A:xt we want to encrypt
```

Comment: There's an extraordinary number of spaces at the end of each line here. A few would be understandable, but there's in excess of 190!

Comment: @tadman fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a different, random IV on the decryption. This value must be identical. That is you capture it when encrypting:

```
iv = cipher.random_iv
```

Then you decrypt using that:

```
cipher.iv = iv
```

Then it decrypts properly. You need the same key + IV pair in order for the decryption to succeed.

Comment: But isn't that the whole point? To rely on the secret/key and not the IV?

Comment: The key is user defined (e.g. passphrase) but the IV is generated or pre-defined. Both are needed to unlock the content. You can always hard-code a particular IV if you prefer, or randomly generate it and store it with the key. Note that hard-coding an IV may expose you to more risks security-wise, but if the stakes are low it's not really a big deal. It just makes it easier to guess your passphrase, as with a fixed IV you don't need to test for all possible IVs.